# ItemsControl with nested ComboBox - where to bind SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

This is a simplified version of a problem I am stuck with in a WPF project. It uses MVVM and Prism, but this is not so important here.

I have two simple classes: a BookType and a Book of this BookType.

```
public class BookType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeName {get; set;}

    public static ObservableCollection<BookType> GetBookTypes()
    {
        ObservableCollection<BookType> bookTypes = new ObservableCollection<BookType>();

        bookTypes.Add(new BookType { Id = 0, TypeName = "German" });
        bookTypes.Add(new BookType { Id = 1, TypeName = "English" });

        return bookTypes;
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public BookType BookType {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public static ObservableCollection<Book> GetBooksInEnglish()
    {
        var englishBookType = BookType.GetBookTypes().FirstOrDefault(bt => bt.TypeName == "English");

        ObservableCollection<Book> books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
            books.Add(new Book { Name = String.Format("Book {0}", i), BookType = englishBookType});

        return books;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Book> GetBooksInGerman()
    {
        var germanBookType = BookType.GetBookTypes().FirstOrDefault(bt => bt.TypeName == "German");

        ObservableCollection<Book> books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            books.Add(new Book { Name = String.Format("Buch {0}", i), BookType = germanBookType });

        return books;
    }
}
```

The ViewModel has a Dictionary of Books, each KeyValuePair consists of the BookType and a list of Books:

```
public Dictionary<BookType, ObservableCollection<Book>> Books { get; set; }
```

and it gets filled like that:

```
var bookTypes = BookType.GetBookTypes();
Books = new Dictionary<BookType, ObservableCollection<Book>>();
Books[bookTypes[0]] = Book.GetBooksInGerman();
Books[bookTypes[1]] = Book.GetBooksInEnglish();
```

The Books Dictionary is the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl with the following template:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Books}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key.TypeName}" />
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding ?????}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is working, I see the BookType.TypeName in the TextBlock and each ComboBox has a list of available Books of this BookType. My question is: where can I bind the SelectedItem to? I need to know which Book is selected for each BookType, and I have to set the SelectedItem back on the ComboBox if I know which Book was selected when loading my ViewModel. Please, no code-behind in the View, it all has to happen in the ViewModel with some kind of property.

Regards
Heiko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a class:

```
class BooksGroup{
    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get {...} set{...} }
    public Book Selected { get {...} set{...} }
}
```

now change

```
Books = new Dictionary<BookType, BooksGroup>();

<StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key.TypeName}" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value.Books}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Value.Selected}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a Dictionary you could have a collection of objects containing the BookType, a list of books and a SelectedBook property.

Then all you would have to do is bind ItemsSource to the List of those objects, make a DataTemplate containing a ComboBox whose ItemsSource would be the list of books and its SelectedItem to the SelectedBook property.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BooksPerType}"><!--The list-->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type BookPerType}"><!--The new type-->
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeName}" />
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Book}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Edit: the ComboBox must contain an ItemTemplate in this case, added it